# Load different music profiles for Alsamixer or kmix

Tags: sound, alsa, music, kmix

I would like to know if it's possible to use or configure different music profiles on (K)ubuntu for different types of music: Pop, Rock, Metal, Rap, etc when listening to that type of music. Preferably through an interface of some sort

I use Kmix or Alsamixer. If you have any tip that could give me a lead to the right program, configuration, etc that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you have uninstalled pulseaudio, (kubuntu ships with pulseaudio) you can install pulseaudio-equalizer. Pulse audio uses ALSA's channel but manages sound settings for individual applications without having to use kmix.

You can install this by typing the following commands in an open terminal.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio-equalizer
```

You should be able to search for pulseaudio-equalizer in the app-search area or you can just use the command `pulseaudio-equalizer`.

The EQ has default setting configurations for various profiles like rock, regge, rap, and even laptop. You can also adjust, save, or even customize your own profile.

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't find it in the repo of 14.04. Does it belong to a specific ppa?

Comment: Never mind. I found it. It's in this PPA
`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8`

Comment: @nawar Thanks, I had no idea that was where I got it from and will update the answer.